# Являются ли битовые операции независимыми от порядка байт?

Tags: c++, битовые-операции, порядок-байт

**Пример.**

```
int n = 1;
std::cout << (n & 1) << std::endl; //  будет ли здесь 1 и на little-endian и на big-endian?
```

Comment: Да, конечно. Кстати, ну если уж на то пошло, то когда байты располагаются так или иначе - то наименьший значащий байт будет с одной стороны. Или вы представляете это как "левый операнд little, а правый - big-endian"? :)

Comment: Не понял вашего вопроса, я имел ввиду результат битовой операции (будет ли он один и тот же на машине с little endian и big endian).

Comment: Медленно и два раза, как для депутата... little-endian: 01 00 00 00 & 01 00 00 00 == 01 00 00 00. Big-endian: 00 00 00 01 & 00 00 00 01 == 00 00 00 01. ***КАК*** можно получить ***не*** 1?

Comment: @Harry согласен, никак.

Comment: endiannes никак не влияет на вычисления, кроме случаев доступа к той же памяти по указателю другого типа. `memcpy`, `fread`, `fwrite`, приведение типа к `unsigned char *` зависят, всё остальное нет.